# Are researchers allowed to harvest addresses and send Stack Overflow users unsolicited emails?

Tags: discussion, email

I received an email from some researchers yesterday (the same research mentioned in [this deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351145/38765)). Are people engaging in research allowed to harvest email addresses from Stack Overflow data, and send unsolicited emails to those researchers?

I don't hate research, but I'd rather any such email come via Stack Overflow.

Related, but about those doing so for commercial purposes: [A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa)

Previous question on Meta StackExchange, but posted before the TOS update: [Does this email I've received go against any of Stack Exchange's policies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268883/does-this-email-ive-received-go-against-any-of-stack-exchanges-policies)

Comment: No, not really. Not by their own ethical standards. See https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56598/60241

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was mentioned in that first post you linked that users in some countries aren't bound by the TOS because the laws in their countries require a user to explicitly accept a TOS rather than assuming implicit agreement just by using the service. So the TOS may not be enforceable on such users whether commercial or academic.  This post was linked: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6042/

Comment: @psubsee2003 When you sign up for a SO account it says something along the lines of "by registering you are agreeing to the TOS." Therefore, creating an account = actively accepting the site's TOS.

Comment: @Ihazkode of course, but you dont have to sign up to use the site, which neans scrappers who haven't signed up *may not* be bound, depending on their local laws

Comment: For what it's worth, I personally don't have any trouble with the e-mail that was sent (other than that it came from some spammy looking Gmail account).  It seemed to be a one-time message.  I think that if you don't want any e-mail at all, you don't have to share your e-mail address.  These are just my opinions though... there's some discussion on this from the last time the Stack Exchange terms were updated:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277459/151435

Comment: I think it should be possible to expose your own address on the profile without fearing that it's going to be abused. The address, if given out, is for one-on-one inbound contacts, not mass mail. This practice should be disallowed.

Comment: How did they get the e-mail in the first place? Do they make a guess by grabbing your name and then append gmail.com hotmail.com etc behind it?

Comment: @Lundin The last time I saw a question like this on Meta, it ended up being a series of links the OP forgot about (something like stackoverflow -> profile -> professional site -> email)